"conda install conda-forge::Package" vs "conda install -c contact-forge"
I tried all morning to install a package using conda install conda-forge::Package:
(py39) C:\>conda install conda-forge::fuzzywuzzy
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -
An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
If your current network has https://repo.anaconda.com blocked, please file a support request with your network engineering team.
'https//repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64'
(py39) C:\>

Sometimes, it made some headway downloading the 1st package before failing:
Downloading and Extracting Packages
openssl-3.0.14     | 7.8 MB    | #####################################5   |  49%

A different syntax worked the first time: conda install -c conda-forge fuzzywuzzy.  The progress output was distinctly different.  I saw no "Downloading and Extracting Packages" and no monitoring of the download progress for openssl-3.0.14.
What is the difference between the two methods of installing from conda-forge?

conda install conda-forge::fuzzywuzzy
conda install -c conda-forge fuzzywuzzy

If I knew they were different, I might have saved a good portion of the day.
